# Banana plant has its youngest leaf dry while other ones seem fine

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, tropical, banana

I have a banana plant for a couple of months already. It has grown a lot during this time so it seems to be a healthy plant but recently the youngest leaf has dried.

Here are two pictures of how it looks:

[image]

[image]

Should it be cut off from there? Is there a chance to save the plant?

What could be the cause of this? I noticed some small insects in the soil, like very small black bugs, they look like "normal" insects but maybe they could be the cause of this?

I find it strange that only the youngest leaf is affected.